# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'var'

Tags: javascript

I'm working on this exercise and for some reason I keep getting that syntaxerror and when I put the number into the game it also says "Uncaught ReferenceError: check is not defined" I'm not sure where I'm going wrong here. Any help is appreciated here as I'm a beginner on my journey to learn javascript. Thanks in advance.

Here's the codepen where I'm trying to create the game:

https://codepen.io/Anozie/pen/qBOwBPq

And here's the code and instructions for those who don't want to click the link:

/* Instructions:
You are going to create a Hot or Cold game. The game will take a guess (a number between 1 and 20) from the user and then check to see if that guess matches a randomly generated number between 1 and 20. If the guess matches the random number, alert the user that they have won and reset the game. If it’s close alert them that they’re hot, if not, cold and to try again. The user should guess until they win, after each guess, alert them if it’s closer, warmer, if it’s farther, colder. The HTML has been provided for you. You will only need to write the javascript portion.
*/

```js
//variables
var guess, answer, diffGuess;

var answer = 20;
var guess = 
var diffGuess = answer - guess;
function submitguess();
document.queryselector(".guessInput").addEventListener('click', submit);
document.queryselector("#guessInput").textcontent = guess;

if (guess === answer){
console.log('You got it right');  
  
}else if (diffGuess >= 1 && diffGuess <= 5){
console.log('You are cold');  
  
}else if (diffGuess >= 6 && diffGuess <= 10){
console.log('You are colder');  
  
}else if (diffGuess >= 11 && diffGuess <= 15){
console.log('You are lukewarm');  
  
}else if (diffGuess >= 16 && diffGuess <= 19){
console.log('You are really warm');  
  
};
```

and here's the HTML

```html
<h2>Hot or Cold Game</h2>
<p>I've picked a random number between 1 and 20. Try to guess the number and I will tell you if you're getting hotter or colder!</p>
<form> 
  <input type="text" class="guess" >
  <input type="submit" value="Submit guess" class="guessInput" onclick="return check()">
</form>
```

Comment: you have left one incomplete line

`var guess =`

3rd line from top

Comment: Pls, check your code properly, and you have a problem with this line of code `var guess =`

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it.

HTML code

```
<h2>Hot or Cold Game</h2>
<p>I've picked a random number between 1 and 20. Try to guess the number and I will tell you if you're getting hotter or colder!</p>
<form> 
  <input id="guess" type="number" class="guess" >
  <input type="submit" value="Submit guess" class="guessInput" id="btn-submit" >
</form>
```

JS code

```
var answer = 20;

function check(){
  var guess = document.getElementById("guess").value;
  guess = Number(guess);
  var diffGuess = Math.abs(answer - guess);
  if (guess === answer){
    console.log('You got it right');  
  }else if (diffGuess >= 1 && diffGuess <= 5){
    console.log('You are cold');  
  }else if (diffGuess >= 6 && diffGuess <= 10){
    console.log('You are colder');  
  }else if (diffGuess >= 11 && diffGuess <= 15){
    console.log('You are lukewarm');  
  }else if (diffGuess >= 16 && diffGuess <= 19){
  console.log('You are really warm');
  }
}

document.getElementById("btn-submit").addEventListener("click", function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  check();
});
```

Edit :- Instead of a series of if-else conditions, you can use Switch statement for better clarity.

Comment: I did not focus on generating the answer randomly. For that instead of var answer = 20, have `var answer = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);` and renew it everytime the user guesses the answer correctly.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I thought to use a switch but I thought that was only for true or false statements.

Comment: that removes the error, but when I submit a number nothing happens even if I enter the answer (20)

Comment: That is because === checks the type of two variables also for equality. You have to let `type="number"` in the input box and convert the guess to number type before  comparing. I will update my answer to reflect these changes.

Comment: I ended up fixing it. I wasn't hitting the "console" button at the bottom, and I also changed the diffGuess in the what if statements to just guess and it gave me the correct answers. Thanks again for all of your help.